# Problems to use AsyncTask

Tags: android, file, android-asynctask, background, copy

I've been trying to implement the AsyncTask but without success.

There is a activity that suppose to show a loading progress while copying all files, and then calls the main activity.

This is the code for my LoadingActivity:

```
package br.com.moon.light;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
        copyAssets();
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private void copyAssets() {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        String[] files = null;
        try {
            files = assetManager.list("");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
        }
        if (files != null) for (String filename : files) {
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                in = assetManager.open(filename);
                File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
                out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                copyFile(in, out);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
            }
            finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // NOOP
                    }
                }
                if (out != null) {
                    try {
                        out.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // NOOP
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDITED

I've improved my code but I still don't get why the layout doesn't show while the program is loading..

here are the .java the .xml files:

LoadingActivity.java

```
package br.com.moon.light;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(10);
        startActivity(intent);
        Copyfiles();
    }

    private class Tasks extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            copyAssets();
            return null;
        }
        protected void OnPostExecute(Void param) {
            finish();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values){
            progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
        }
    }

    private void copyAssets() {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        String[] files = null;
        try {
            files = assetManager.list("");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
        }
        if (files != null) for (String filename : files) {
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                in = assetManager.open(filename);
                File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
                out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                copyFile(in, out);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
            }
            finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // NOOP
                    }
                }
                if (out != null) {
                    try {
                        out.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // NOOP
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }

    private void Copyfiles(){
        new Tasks().execute();
    }
}
```

activity_loading.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".LoadingActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:minHeight="20dip"
        android:maxHeight="20dip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="159dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've updated with the full code... The app starts with a blank screen then shows the Main Activity... If I press the back button, it shows the damn progress bar. I'd like to have the progress bar or at least a text informing the program is loading while it copies hundreds of PDF files in background.

Answer (score 0):

```
private class Tasks extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoadingActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Files. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        copyAssets();
        return null;
    }
    protected void OnPostExecute(Void param) {
       // dismiss the dialog after getting all files
        pDialog.dismiss();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Note: Declare

> private ProgressDialog pDialog;

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange thing, why you call `startActivity` of `MainActivity` in  `onCreate` method ?

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setMax(10);
        startActivity(intent);
        Copyfiles();
    }
```